# Internal compile error c++ cilk plus

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cilk-plus, cilk

[Fixed]- Explanation given in comments

[Updated with error screenshot]
   I am getting a compilation error when compiled using gcc/5.4.0. Following is the error reported:

> internal compiler error: in lower_stmt, at gimple-low.c:397
>                cilk_spawn m_sparsify_graph_helper__(mdl, n_pa, n_ch, score2beat);

Following is the code snippet that causes error:

```
void m_sparsify_graph_helper__(MDL mdl, set_type pa, set_type ch, std::vector<double> score2beat) {
        //cilk::reducer<cilk::op_list_append<RNode_>> rlist;
        //"rlist" - defined in the class as a private variable

        if (ch == 0) { return; } 

        set_type n_ch = ch;

        // Some more code -- which I am very sure is not causing error

        int lsb = n_ - 1;
        for (; lsb >= 0; --lsb) { if (in_set(pa, lsb)) { break; } }

        if (lsb == n_ - 1) { return; }

        set_type n_pa = set_add(pa, lsb + 1);
        int n_pa_sz = set_size(n_pa);
        if (n_pa_sz >= n_) { return; }

        BitCombination comb(n_pa, n_pa_sz, n_);

        for (;;) {
            n_pa = comb.data();
            // If cilk_spawn keyword removed it compiles fine.
            cilk_spawn m_sparsify_graph_helper__(mdl, n_pa, n_ch, score2beat);
            if (!comb.next() || in_set(n_pa, n_ - 1)) { break; }
        }

    }// m_sparsify_graph_helper__
```

I assume it's a compiler error but I would like to know what is the way to circumvent this error and get the code executed warning and error free.

Error screenshot:
[image: Error scrrenshot]

Comment: An ICE is always a compiler error, regardless of whether the source code is valid or not. Report it.

Comment: Is that all it says about the internal error?

Comment: @TrevorHickey Added the complete error screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the reported errors was ironed out in the GCC 6.X release.

FYI, if you are facing similar issue try to reproduce the error on the latest release of GCC just to confirm whether it was earlier reported and rectified or not.